# Azure Web App Powershell Resource Manager Mode - Connection String Slot Setting

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm adding Connection Strings to my Azure Web App using the AzureResourceManager mode in Powershell.

Using the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) I've found the correct Powershell to add a connection string to my web app

```
$PropertiesObject = @{
    #Property = value;
    MembershipConnection = @{
        Value = "Server=tcp:members.database.windows.net,1433;Database=Membership;User ID=User@members;Password=passwordgoeshere;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
        Type = "2";
    }
}

New-AzureResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $resGroup -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "$siteName/connectionstrings" -OutputObjectFormat New -ApiVersion "2015-08-01" -Force
```

However, I can't find a way of marking the Connection String as a Slot Setting, so that it doesn't move when switching between my Staging and Production deployment slots.

In the Portal, it's a simple checkbox alongside the connection string.

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You might already know that you can do this in the Azure Service Management Mode like this:

```
> Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureServiceManagement
> Set-AzureWebsite -Name myapp -SlotStickyConnectionStringNames @("my_db")
```

I appreciate, though, that your question is about using the Azure Resource Manager.

Comment: Hello. Thanks @shaun-luttin, I did not know that was possible, so that's great because it will at least get the job done for now! I would still like to know if it's possible in Resource Manager mode though.

Comment: I too would like to know how to do it with the Resource Manager mode. I have posted a few questions around the web and will update my answer when I know. http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/11/azure-websites-slots/#.VecTH_Tdtu9 and http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/5795103-the-ability-to-swap-website-slots-without-swapping I have also asked on Yammer.